# Multiple operations at same time gives 0.0 as output.Calculator using swing

Tags: java, swing, calculator, actionlistener, actionevent

I created a calculator using **Java swing**.Frame creation and button arrangements were all set.I used **ActionListener interface**.And the program were execute successfully,when i performed a single operation along with two operands(eg:5+2). Working is success so far.But when I try to do multiple operations at same time with more than two operands(eg:10+2-5),it gives me 0.0 as output everytime.But I need my calculator to perform multiple operations at the same time .And should also follow the BODMAS rule.

I declared a **float array** named result and a **char array** named operation,as global variables.

```
public Calculator implements ActionListener{
float[] result=new float[10];
char[] operation=new char[10];
int i=0;
isOperationClicked=false;
```

Here is one example of operation button(like +,-,/,*) ,defined inside the **actionPerformed** function along with else if ladder.

```
else if(e.getSource()==plusbutton) {
            isOperationClicked=true;
            String oldValue=displaylabel.getText();
            result=new float[10];
            result[i]=Float.parseFloat(oldValue);
            operation=new char[10];
            operation[i]= '+';
            i++;
            }
```

Also **equaltobotton** is defined inside the **actionPerformed**  function.Checking each operation symbols with ‘if’ on a ‘while loop’.Here i put one example.

```
else if(e.getSource()==equaltobutton) {
            int m=0;
            String finalvalue=displaylabel.getText();
            float finalvalueF=Float.parseFloat(finalvalue);
            result[i]=finalvalueF;
            while(m<i) {
                if(operation[m]=='/') {
                    float res=result[m]/result[m+1];
                    result=removeArrayF(result,m);
                    result[m]=res;
                    operation=removeArrayC(operation,m);
                    i--;m--;
                }
                m++;
            }
```

For display the result

```
displaylabel.setText(result[0]+"");
```

This **setText** function is also include on the last line of **equaltobutton**'s action

The **removearrayF** and the **removearrayC** are two methods defined to remove one element from the array.
This is what i do .what are the changes i need to do for the proper output for multiple operations at same time?

Comment: Can you provide a pseudo-code rendering of how the process works?  How is the data stored as the user enters the values, i.e., the _operation_ array, and the _result_ array.

Comment: To me, this sounds like you need to remove the UI from the equation and debug your algorithm

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question to show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't understand why you re-create the `result` array on each operation (`result=new float[10];`), this seems like a bad idea.  Personally, I'd use a `StringBuilder` and `append` each value/operand and then, when required, convert that to a `char` array (or simply pop each char off the `StringBuilder`, which ever makes sense for you)

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you give an algoritham to fix it!?

Comment: I get the idea of String builder class. But how do make it possible on this situation